# How to not stretch height of child of flex div

Tags: css

I have some child div's in a parent div that uses flexbox.
The parent div has min-height:100%.

When I add a child div that has very little contents, I want the width to stretch to 100% of it's parent (which it does), bot not the height.

If the div contains only 2 lines of text, the height of the div should be just the height of the text inside, and not take up the rest of the space available in the parent.

How to solve this?

```
See http://jsfiddle.net/brqzLcb4/
```

3v
I don't want the green "homepage" div's to become "higher" than necessary.

Comment: can you show us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/brvzLcb4/1/

add `align-content: flex-start;` to `.pagecontent` it will work as you wanted

Comment: Thank you! Do you also have a tip for me to keep the margin between the two divs the same as on the border?