# Stop `display: flex` from changing height of child

Tags: css, flexbox

Very simple setup:

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  padding: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <a>Foo</a>
</div>
```

Toggling the `display: flex` style in devtools shows the content height of the `<div>` alternating between 22 & 26px. I need this to not happen, and for the height to remain as it was originally.

I've messed around with `align-items`, `flex`, `flex-grow`, `flex-basis`, etc. but none seem to stop this bizarre resizing.

Comment: display:inline-block to the link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to not stretch height of child of flex div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639195/how-to-not-stretch-height-of-child-of-flex-div)

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks (`a`) have a `display` property of `inline` by default and so vertical padding does not take effect.

When the parent has `display: flex`, the link is no longer `inline` but is a flex child and so "blockified" and thus the vertical padding takes effect.

I'd suggest making your links `display: inline-block` by default in your CSS reset or some other means, perhaps a special class for links you wish to act this way.

Answer (score -1):

This is very much flex inherit behaviour and the resulting size dependes on the parent height, flex is set on as you didnt set a height value on the child.

Using height: max-content;  on the child will most probably result in your expected behaviour.

I'd also recommend learning more about flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/